# Golang Map of http.ResponseWriters

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a map that stores http.ResponseWriters so that I can write to them later, after a separate thread has done the relevant computation. 
The map is defined in my main as follow:
`jobs := make(map[uint32]http.ResponseWriter)`
I then pass this map to a handle function like so:

```
r.HandleFunc("/api/{type}/{arg1}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    typ, _ := strconv.Atoi(mux.Vars(r)["type"])
    AddReqQueue(w, ReqQueue, typ, mux.Vars(r)["arg1"], jobs, ids)
}).Methods("get")
```

After that I process the reuqeuest and add it to a channel:

```
func AddReqQueue(w http.ResponseWriter, ReqQueue chan mssg.WorkReq, typ int, arg1 string, jobs map[uint32]http.ResponseWriter, ids []uint32) {
    var id uint32
    id, ids = ids[0], ids[1:] // get a free work id
    jobs[id] = w
    fmt.Println("Adding req to queue")
    ReqQueue <- mssg.WorkReq{Type: uint8(typ), Arg1: arg1, WId: id}
}
```

Inside this function I have tested and am able to write data to the ReponseWriter, however later when I try to use the map in:

```
func SendResp(RespQueue chan mssg.WorkResp, jobs map[uint32]http.ResponseWriter) {
for {
    resp := <-RespQueue
    jobs[resp.WId].Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    _, err := jobs[resp.WId].Write(resp.Data) // ERROR IS COMING FROM HERE
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Fatal error: %s", err.Error())
    }
}
```

}

It doesn't work. No matter what I pre-set the header too or try to write (even just a simple string I hardcoded) I get a err of

```
Conn.Write wrote more than the declared Content-Length
```

I know I'm accessing the right struct in the map, it just seems as if the `ReponseWriter` has gone out of context or been corrupted, also i know that the headers shouldn't really matter since it is the first time I am calling `Write()` and therefore it should create the headers for me.

Comment: When you call `AddReqQueue` in your handler, your handler returns since  you're not blocking it.

Comment: That is what I desired. When the handler returns, does it mark the ResponseWriter for GC? That would seem strange considering I still keep track of it in the map.

Comment: The goroutine responsible for the ResponseWriter exits. A 'better' way would be to trigger the work, block in the handler, write the work to a buffer, and then `io.Copy(buf, w)` to write it out back in the handler. Set a timeout to prevent the HTTP connection from timing out on the client side.

Comment: Build with `-race` and fix the races that it will quickly find and report. (I.e. HTTP handlers run in their own goroutines, maps cannot be accessed concurrently without synchronization).

Answer (score 2):

@elithrar was correct. I wasn't aware that the http.ResponseWriter object became invalid after the handler exited. If I just force my handler to wait, it works fine.